# How to find the current user Lat/Longt and pass it to another method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cllocationmanager

I'm able to find the current user Lat/Longt from the locationManager method below. What I need to do is then pass these variables to the Google Places API method (also shown below). The problem I'm having is that I have a null value for both the myLat and myLongt in the **ParseXML_of_Google_PlacesAP** method. The values are outputted correctly in the locationManager method though.

thanks for any help

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
        didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
               fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
    {
        int degrees = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
        double decimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.latitude - degrees);
        int minutes = decimal * 60;
        double seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;
        myLat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"", 
                         degrees, minutes, seconds];
        latLabel.text = myLat;
        degrees = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
        decimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.longitude - degrees);
        minutes = decimal * 60;
        seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;
        myLongt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"", 
                           degrees, minutes, seconds];
        longLabel.text = myLongt;


        NSLog(@"myLat is %@ myLongt is %@ from location mgr", myLat, myLongt);
    }


-(void)ParseXML_of_Google_PlacesAPI
{

    NSURL *googlePlacesURL=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=bar,@%&radius=500&types=bar&sensor=false&key=myAPIKey",myLat,myLongt]];

    NSLog(@"lat is %@ longt is %@", myLat, myLongt);

    NSData *xmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:googlePlacesURL];
    xmlDocument = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc]initWithData:xmlData options:0 error:nil];

    NSArray *arr = [xmlDocument.rootElement elementsForName:@"result"];

    for(GDataXMLElement *e in arr )
    {
        [placesOutputArray addObject:e];
    } 
}
```

Comment: can you show us how `myLat` and `myLongt` are **declared**? thanks!

Comment: NSString *myLongt;
    NSString *myLat; 
like this in the .h file. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I just store it in the NSUserdefaults. So in your case it could look like that:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:myLat forKey:@"currentLat"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:myLongt forKey:@"currentLongt"];
```

and then, I read it back from every method I like just with that:

```
NSString *currentLat = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"currentLat"];
NSString *currentLongt = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"currentLongt"];
```

Answer (score 2):

As myLat and myLongt is NSString which shows value null means it is getting released.

So retain both object after feeding value.

```
 myLat = nil;
 myLat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"", 
                     degrees, minutes, seconds];
 [myLat retain];
```

Also,

```
 myLongt = nil;
 myLongt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"", 
                       degrees, minutes, seconds];
 [myLongt retain];
```